# Ajax call to my Wordpress website from an external application

Tags: php, ajax, rest-api

I have on website on wordpress and a external web app. I try to make an AJAX call from this external web app to get some info from my wordpress site/ database but i got an error message 400.

Here is my ajax call code :

```
        jQuery.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url: "https://www.groupio.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        contentType: 'json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        responseType:'json',

        data: {
            action : "itempricingfunction",
            ean : "EANTEST0101010"
        },

        success:function(data){

            alert(data);

        },

        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
        });
```

and here is my functions.php file inside my wordpress website :

```
function itempricingfunction(){


$product_ean = (isset($_POST['ean'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['ean']) : NULL;
echo json_encode(array('product_ean' =>$product_ean));


    exit;
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_itempricingfunction", "itempricingfunction");
add_action("wp_ajax_itempricingfunction", "itempricingfunction");
```

The response from wordpress is error 404.

Can you help me to communicate and set/get some data from my worpdress website please ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX request from Chrome Extension to Wordpress Website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/356822/ajax-request-from-chrome-extension-to-wordpress-website)

Comment: Is the error 400 or 404? You've said both, but they're different errors that mean different things. It's important to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be sending your data as JSON:

```
dataType: "JSON"
```

For `add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_itempricingfunction"` to work, WordPress needs to find the `action` parameter in your request, which you're correctly setting here:

```
    data: {
        action : "itempricingfunction",
        ean : "EANTEST0101010"
    },
```

The problem is that it checks this using `$_REQUEST['action']`, but PHP doesn't populate `$_REQUEST` with JSON. It only works with form data. So remove the `dataType` line and you should be fine:

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.groupio.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        responseType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'itempricingfunction',
            ean: 'EANTEST0101010'
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            alert( data );
        },
        error: function( errorThrown ) {
            console.log( errorThrown );
        }
    }
);
```

There's a couple of other things to consider too:

- If the web app is on a different domain, you may run into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues.
- A [custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) would be more appropriate for this sort of thing, and does support receiving data as JSON.